# SQL Server Reporting Services Custom Page Layouts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Would it be possible to define layouts depending on the report type? ie. The layout size for PDFs would be different from the web layout.

Let's say we publish the report to the web. The user has the option of exporting this custom report to PDF. We want to be able to specify how the report should look like when exported to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The layout has to be defined before the report is even rendered. The report has no advance knowledge of what form it is going to take when exported.

My advice is to either:

- Create two separate reports with separate layouts depending on whether it is to become a PDF or a Webpage.
- Tweak your layout so it will export nicely to both formats.